# @font face rules loading fonts twice?

Tags: css, http, firefox, fonts

On a I'm working on the custom font is being requested twice.
Basically when I view the net panel on firebug it shows  all two of four custom fonts being requested 2 times.   [image: network traffic]
I've checked the css and they are only being declared once.

Any ideas?

Comment: another reason "font-face loading twice" happens is that `Cache-Control: max-age=0` for the font (check the response headers in the web inspector).  If it's set to never cache like this, and you reference your font face in multiple styles, it might load multiple times and cause flashing.  This is probably because the first reference to the font hasn't finished downloading when the second reference is called, and since there's no caching, it downloads it again, something like that.  Just in case you googled for that and this question came up.

Comment: @Lance Even setting max-age to a year the issue persists. tested on Chrome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're experiencing this bug:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=668178

In short, Firebug is causing the issue. Insane, right?

I tested your site with Wireshark (a lot), and the fonts *are* only downloaded twice while Firebug is active.

Comment: Nice, I'll just ignore that then :)

Comment: For what it's worth, a bug report has been filed with Firebug, so this will probably be fixed in the future: http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4649

Comment: This bug appears to be fixed in the latest Firebug 1.9 beta.

Comment: Firebug is still doing it in Firebug 1.10.0

Comment: Firebug still doing it in 1.11.1

Comment: Not just firebug, happens in chrome too.